# Forcing line break in the textarea after 38 characters using jquery

Tags: javascript

[1](http://jsfiddle.net/e5w5z/8/)Heres is my code but I am dont know how to add a line break and allow the user to continue typing. With the alert message is fine but I just want the user to continue typing and line break added by the script.

```
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict( true );
dom.query(document).ready(function() {
    // var myTA = dom.query('#remaining_chars');
    //alert(myTA[0].scrollHeight); 
    dom.query('#ta').keypress(function() {
        var text =dom.query(this).val();
        var arr = text.split("\n");
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i].length > 38) {
                alert("Not more than 38 characters per line! Continue in next line!");
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent characters from appearing
            }
        }

        console.log(text);
        dom.query('#ta').val(text);
    });
});
```

Link to the code :http://jsfiddle.net/e5w5z/8/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/e5w5z/8/)

Comment: you can add a `/n` to the existing text.

Comment: remove the `alert` and just do `dom.query(this).val(text+"\n"))` ?

Comment: what are you ultimately doing with the data? you can't MAKE them do this client-side anyways (if nothing else, they can have js disabled). So instead of enforcing this, why not just parse it into 38 char chunks server-side? Or if it's solely client-side stuff.. just use js to parse into 38 char chunks anyways. Don't bother the user with this sort of thing IMO

Comment: it would also be helpful to both yourself and others if you post a jsfiddle of your current code. That way others can update it with something that works and you can see it working in action so that you can more easily apply a solution

Comment: @CrayonViolent when i add dom.query('#ta').val(text+"\n"); to the code , the next line only accepts one character and than line breaks http://jsfiddle.net/e5w5z/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will automatically insert line breaks if the user continues to type and never backtracks.  This only analyzes the last line in the textarea.  Therefore, if they go back to a previous line and begin editing, they will be able to type more than the max characters allowed per line.  It should be possible to have this analyze every line, but you'd have to write some more involved logic in order to insert line breaks at the correct positions and set the caret position properly after changing the textarea contents.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7V3kY/1/

```
var LINE_LENGTH_CHARS = 38;

$(function(){

    $(document).on('input propertychange','textarea',function(e){
        // Something was typed into the textarea
        var lines = $(this).val().split("\n");
        var last_line = lines[lines.length-1];
            if (last_line.length >= LINE_LENGTH_CHARS) {

                // Resetting the textarea val() in this way has the 
                // effect of adding a line break at the end of the 
                // textarea and putting the caret position at the 
                // end of the textarea
                $(this).val($(this).val()+"\n");

            }
    });
});
```